# Reload Page and Filter data After selecting item in DropDownButton in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, dropdownbutton

I have a page that displays all products from a rest Api. On the same page I have a `DropDownButton` which is populated with the various categories. My question is how can I filter the data after selecting an item from the dropdown button and also reload the page with the filtered data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to work it out like this for anyone who it may help.

```
InkWell(
                                      onTap: () {
                                        clearimage();
                                      },
                                      child: Row(
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          Icon(
                                            Icons.cancel,
                                            color: red,
                                            size: 13.0,
                                          ),
                                          Padding(
                                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                                left: 15.0),
                                            child: Text(
                                              "Remove",
                                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
```

i called a method `clearimage();` i had to `File _mage` back to `null`

```
  clearimage() {
    setState(() {
      _image = null;
    });
  }
```